# How to create a task scheduler which one run my .py file in every hour in every day?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I want to run python code with the Windows task scheduler (so automate it), which is in a .py (Python 2.7) format. How can I run this code in every hour?

I know that how I have to open it

(To open Task Scheduler, enter “sched” (without quotes) in the Start search box

A three-pane console will open

In the Actions pane on the right, click “Create Basic Task…”...), but I don't know what I have to set up to run this code in the correct way in every 1 hour in every day.

Comment: If you're using Linux you can use crontab

Comment: I am using windows 7

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import schedule
import time
def task():
    print "Hello"
schedule.every(60).minutes.do(task)
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I already wrote a code which is inside in my scripts, and it looks like you suggested for me too :) but the problem is that sometimes (after 2-3 hours) the script stop without error message, and nothing happening. Thats why i want to try with this task scheduler